# How to draw using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a latex beginner and I have seen lots of examples here that are beautiful works in TikZ. My problem is that TikZ requires some very precise values (like coordinates and sizes) and my only way to deal with them is by trial end error. And it requires a lot of trial and error, even if the drawing is relatively simple.

So, how do you find appropriate values for your shape (probably I'm not using the correct terminology here, sorry for this) sizes and coordinates?

Comment: Just start drawing something.  Then, practice, practice, practice, practice.  After a while you'll get the hang of it.  And there are always folks here willing to give you a helping hand.  But right now your question is a vague.  So it's hard to give anything more than advice.

Comment: It may be helpful to use an editor with "real time" display of the outcome for that purpose, such as [gummi](https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi). [qtikz](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/) may also be of help.

Comment: Can you post an example of a small document which shows the results of your trial-and-error approach? Maybe somebody could then suggest how they would have tackled the same problem. (The answer might be 'trial-and-error' - sometimes, it is. But it might not be.)

Answer (score 4):

A simple way of finding good coordinates for a shape is drawing a help grid, such as:

```
\draw[help lines, step=0.5] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
```

It helps in first positioning. After fine-tuning, you can remove that grid line.